# Why pressing Esc and then O from insert mode has this behavior?

Tags: key-bindings

When I'm in insert mode, for instance just between the two `l`s in `hello`, and press <kbd>Escape</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> (i.e. <kbd>Escape</kbd><kbd>Shift+o</kbd>), the opening of the line above is not instantaneous. Specifically I see all this in little time

- in the short interval between pressing <kbd>Escape</kbd> and <kbd>Shift+o</kbd>, I see

  1. the cursor flashing to the first `l`,
  2. and after a ***very short time*** jumping back to the second `l`,
- after I also press <kbd>Shift+o</kbd>

  3. see the upper case `O` printed on place of the second `l`, and
  4. and after a ***slightly longer time*** the empty line is created above the line I was editing (and the `l` is back).

The point is that if I start writing right after the <kbd>Shift+o</kbd>, i.e. ***between step 3 and 4***, whether the empty line is created depends on what I write. For instance, I write `o` (lower case) the empty line is not created, and a `/` is inserted between the two `l`s.

If I just press <kbd>Escape</kbd> I see

1. I see the cursor flashing to the first `l`,
2. and immediately jumping back to the second `l`,
3. and, after a slightly longer time, it goes again on the first `l`.

I think this has to do with some `imap`/`inoremap`-ping which I'm not aware of, or which I simply don't expect to be triggered when hitting <kbd>Escape</kbd><kbd>Shift+o</kbd>.

Further info:

```
:set timeout? ttimeout? timeoutlen? ttimeoutlen? term?
  timeout
nottimeout
  timeoutlen=1000
  ttimeoutlen=-1
  term=xterm-256color
```

In the following screencast I'm using my vimrc, but I observe the same behavior even when I delete it. On the other hand I don't when I lauch Vim via `vim -u NONE`.

[image: asciicast]

Comment: What is `:set timeout? ttimeout? timeoutlen? ttimeoutlen? term?` (I suspect you're hitting esc-O fast enough to trigger some kind of decision between an escape sequence and the actual keys)

Comment: I have the same suspicion, also in light of the fact that `Alt-whatever` mappings have the same escape sequence as `Escape` followed by `whatever`. I'll add the answer to your question in my question.

Comment: `<Esc>O` is also special in that it's often the prefix of the escape codes produced by arrow keys (`<Esc>OA` through `<Esc>OD`) and the first four F-keys (`<Esc>OP` through `<Esc>OS`.) I think it has more to do with that rather than with the `Alt` sequences.